# IOS UICollectionView Selection issue

Tags: ios, uicollectionview, ios8, xcode6

My `UICollectionView` has a strange behavior, when user taps on `UICollectionViewCell`.

In my assumption, according to apple docs, when user taps on `UICollectionViewCell`, cell should become highlighted and then selected.

But in my app, when user taps on cell, it only becomes highlighted, not selected.

And when user swipes on cell, and only in this case, cell becomes selected.

Any help, please. Xcode 6 is used.

I use UICollectionView from the box, with custom UICollectionViewCell class, which overrides `setSelected` and `setHighlighted`. I've implemented these methods

```
- (BOOL)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView shouldSelectItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
- (void)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView didHighlightItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
- (void)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView didSelectItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
- (void)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView didDeselectItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

but only for check.

---

**UPD:**
I've captured the video http://take.ms/LzBkZ.

Also provide the code:

```
**UICollectionViewController**
- (BOOL)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView shouldSelectItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    NSLog(@"should");
    return YES;
}

- (void)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView didHighlightItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    NSLog(@"highlighted");
}

- (void)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView didSelectItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    NSLog(@"select %@", indexPath);
    _selectedCategory = _source[(NSUInteger) indexPath.row];
//  _selectedNumber = [NSNumber numberWithInteger:category.id];
}

- (void)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView didDeselectItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    NSLog(@"deselect %@", indexPath);

    if (_selectedCategory) {
        _selectedCategory = nil;
    }

}
```

And

```
**SSCustomViewCell**
- (void)setSelected:(BOOL)selected
{
    [super setSelected:selected];

    self.alpha = (CGFloat) (selected ? 0.4 : 1);

    [self setNeedsDisplay];

}

- (void)setHighlighted:(BOOL)highlighted
{
    [super setHighlighted:highlighted];

    self.alpha = (CGFloat) (highlighted ? 0.5 : 1);
    [self setNeedsDisplay];
}
```

Comment: Ensure you are calling `super` in overridden `setSelected:` and `setHilighted:`, and returning `YES` from `collectionView:shouldSelectItemAtIndexPath:`

Comment: Of course i do this. Add code and video to question

Comment: So, your problem is `collectionView:shouldSelectItemAtIndexPath:` is not even called. Are you using any `UIGestureRecognizer`?

Comment: I can mark your comment as answer. I have a `tap recognizer` on whole view, this causes this problem. Maybe you have any ideas how to remain `tap gesture recognizer` on whole view and at the same time allow selection in `UICollectionView`, as out of the box, without any hacks, something like `preventPropogation` in js?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A `UITapGesutureRecognizer` prevents propagating touch event to `UIView` **by default**. see [the docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIGestureRecognizer_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIGestureRecognizer/cancelsTouchesInView)

You can disable this feature by unchecking 'Cancels touches in view' in IB or following by code:

```
UITapGestureRecognizer *recognizer = self.myTapGestureRecognizer;
recognizer.cancelsTouchesInView = NO;
```